# Простая проверка полей на заполненность

Tags: html, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать проверку полей на заполненность. Мне бы подошел обычный required, но он не работает в Safari.

У меня такая форма:

```js
$(".form").submit(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    $(this).find("input").val("");
    alert("Отправлено");

    $(".form").trigger("reset");
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон *" required="" name="phone">
  <button class="button">Отправить визитку</button>
</form>
```

Желательно показать примером на основе моей формы, для понимания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По аналогии и телефон, для телефона есть плагины jquery с маской, проверкой на цифры и т.д.

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  //ЕСЛИ СИМВОЛОВ ИМЕНИ > 4 И СИМВОЛОВ ТЕЛЕФОНА >10
  if ($('#name').val().length > 4 && $('#phone').val().length > 10) {
    //ОТПРАВЛЯЕТЕ ФОРМУ
    alert('success');
  }
  //ЕСЛИ УСЛОВИЕ НЕ ВЫПОЛНЕНО
  else {
    //УВЕДОМЛЯЕТЕ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ АЛЕРТОМ/БЛОКОМ/ЛЮБЫМ ВАМ УДОБНЫМ СПОСОБОМ И НЕ ОТПРАВЛЯЕТЕ ФОРМУ
    alert('warning');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон *" required="" name="phone" id="phone">
  <button class="button" id="submit">Отправить визитку</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Это я понимаю, мы обрабатываем клик. Но мне нужно делать проверку перед отправкой формы. Как это сделать?
Сейчас проверка и отправка работают сами по себе. Например в сафари мне выдаст ошибку что поле не заполнено но форма всё равно отправится.

Comment: добавьте после if блок else в котором и производите отправку. Если условие выполняется (в примере поменять "< 4" на ">4") то отправляете форму, если оно не выполняется не отправляете и уведомляете пользователя. сейчас поправлю код.

Comment: пропущено `return false;` после `alert('warning');`

Comment: @Igor спасибо, сейчас добавлю

Answer (score 0):

метод *.val( value )* в *Jquery* устанавливает элементу значение *value*. Просто метод *.val()* возвращает текущие значение элемента.
Можно сделать так: находим элемент проверяем или заполнено поле если да то *alert* если нет то *nul*

```
$(this).find("input").val().length > 0 ? alert("Отправлено") : null
```